# Hacer un useState en Javascript

Tags: javascript, usestate

Estoy leyendo sobre los `useState` y quise hacer mi propio código para hacerme una idea de como funcionan.

Pero solo consigo que me muestre el primer valor, y el segundo nunca se cambia.

Tengo un botón que al apretarlo debería cambiar el contenido de la variable, pero sigue mostrando el original.

```
const PruebaUseState = () => {

  //Funcion principal
  const funcionState = (primerValor) => {
    let original = primerValor;

    //Funcion que cambia variable
    const cambioVariable = (segundoValor) => {
      original = segundoValor;
    };

    return [original, cambioVariable];
  };

  const [primero, segundo] = funcionState("Gato");

  console.log(primero);

  //Funcion que se activa al apretar el boton
  const cambiarVariable = () => {
    segundo("Perro");
    console.log(primero);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={cambiarVariable}>Cambiar</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default PruebaUseState;
```

Comment: Esto es react supongo?

Comment: Si tu pregunta es sobre cómo usar `useState` en ReactJs te recomiendo que leas la [documentacion oficial](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html). Si tu pregunta es sobre cómo funciona el hook `useState` por detrás y quieres hacerlo con JS puro, te recomiendo que veas este [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2mMOiCSj5c) en donde explican cómo funciona react  usando JS puro

Comment: Yo lo hice con el `hook` y un `if` [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-bessie-gby81q?file=/src/App.js) pero supongo que tú lo hiciste así porque quieres saber cómo funciona el `hook` a fondo por así decirlo, no se.

Comment: Primero, useState es un hook de react, por ende tu pregunta está mal formulada. Segundo, useState no es nada mas que un hook en el que se puede almacenar un estado, por lo que entiendo, lo que queres hacer es crear tu propio hook que es algo que react permite. Si ese es el caso, hay varios errores en tu código: aquí return [original, cambioVariable]; sólo deberías retornar original, cambioVariable es una función, no un valor. Tu variable llamada "segundo" está declarada en un bloque, por ende su alcance es sólo para ese bloque, cuando la llamas más abajo con el nuevo valor, no existe. Tercero,